# Algo curioso en JavaScript y HTML, ¿Por que este código no funciona así como esta?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css3

Estos son 3 Códigos que iré explicando, en su cabecera, que es lo que cambia en cada uno.
Después de darle vueltas di en el problema, y es que; la etiqueta `imput`(type="chekbox") y el método `.toggle` no pueden estar al mismo tiempo; si borro `input` el código cambia el fondo a purpura; y si mantengo `input` cambiando `.toggle` por `.add` el código logra cambiar la imagen y vuelve el fondo purpura .

**Lo que no entiendo o la pregunta es, ¿Por qué el código no funciona así como esta?.**

**1ºCódigo** debería tener de resultado, que al hacer click sobre la imagen; cambie la imagen y el fondo se vuelva purpura.

```js
let text = document.querySelector(".text");
let alternar = document.querySelector(".alternar");

alternar.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
       document.body.classList.toggle("purple");
});
```

```css
/* No mostramos:
- La casilla de verificación
- La primera imagen si está marcada la casilla.
- La segunda imagen si no lo está.
*/
.alternar > input,
.alternar > input:checked + img,
.alternar > input + img + img {
  display: none;
}

/* Invertimos la lógica. Mostramos:
- La primera imagen cuando no esté marcada la casilla.
- La segunda imagen cuando lo esté.
*/
.alternar > input + img,
.alternar > input:checked + img + img {
  display: block;
}

.alternar > span {
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 24px;
   color: red;
}

.purple{
   background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<label class="alternar">
  <span>CLICK ME</span><input type="checkbox" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="Imagen 1" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/210/200" alt="Imagen 2" />
</label>
```

**2º** cambio `.toggle` por `.add`.

```js
let text = document.querySelector(".text");
let alternar = document.querySelector(".alternar");

alternar.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
       document.body.classList.add("purple");
});
```

```css
.alternar > input,
.alternar > input:checked + img,
.alternar > input + img + img {
  display: none;
}

.alternar > input + img,
.alternar > input:checked + img + img {
  display: block;
}

.alternar > span {
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 24px;
   color: red;
}

.purple{
   background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<label class="alternar">
  <span>CLICK ME</span><input type="checkbox" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="Imagen 1" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/210/200" alt="Imagen 2" />
</label>
```

**3º** borro `input` y mantengo `.toggle`.

```js
let text = document.querySelector(".text");
let alternar = document.querySelector(".alternar");

alternar.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
       document.body.classList.toggle("purple");
});
```

```css
.alternar > input,
.alternar > input:checked + img,
.alternar > input + img + img {
  display: none;
}
.alternar > input + img,
.alternar > input:checked + img + img {
  display: block;
}

.alternar > span {
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 24px;
   color: red;
}
.purple{
   background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<label class="alternar">
  <span>CLICK ME</span>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="Imagen 1" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/210/200" alt="Imagen 2" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código funciona correctamente, pero no como esperas, porque se están disparando dos eventos:

1. Clic en imagen o texto. Normal, porque son los elementos que puede recibir realmente el clic. Ahí se cambia la clase correctamente.
2. Al estar dentro de un `<label>` se lanza nuevamente un evento clic para aplicar cambio al `input`. Ahí se vuelve a cambiar la clase, ¿incorrectamente? No, porque esa es la forma en que funciona.

Puedes comprobar este comportamiento agregando `console.log(e.target);` después de cambiar la clase.

```js
let text = document.querySelector(".text");
let alternar = document.querySelector(".alternar");

alternar.addEventListener("click", e => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("purple");
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

```css
.purple {
   background-color: purple;
}
/* No mostramos:
- La casilla de verificación
- La primera imagen si está marcada la casilla.
- La segunda imagen si no lo está.
*/
.alternar > input,
.alternar > input:checked + img,
.alternar > input + img + img {
  display: none;
}

/* Invertimos la lógica. Mostramos:
- La primera imagen cuando no esté marcada la casilla.
- La segunda imagen cuando lo esté.
*/
.alternar > input + img,
.alternar > input:checked + img + img {
  display: block;
}

.alternar > span {
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 24px;
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="alternar">
  <span>CLICK ME</span><input type="checkbox" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="Imagen 1" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/210/200" alt="Imagen 2" />
</label>
```

El segundo fragmento de código "funciona" cambiando el fondo solo una vez, porque tienes `.add`, pero no `.remove` para alternar.

El tercer fragmento "funciona" alternando el fondo, pero no las imágenes, porque eliminaste el `input` que, por medio de CSS, es el encargado de ese trabajo.

### ¿Solución?

Cambiar el tipo de evento a escuchar, en este caso, lo que realmente importa es aplicar los cambios cuando el `input` esté marcado o desmarcado.

```js
let text = document.querySelector(".text");
// Usar input en vez de etiqueta
let alternar = document.querySelector(".alternar input");

// Escuchar cambios en el input
alternar.addEventListener('change', e => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("purple");
});
```

```css
.purple {
   background-color: purple;
}
/* No mostramos:
- La casilla de verificación
- La primera imagen si está marcada la casilla.
- La segunda imagen si no lo está.
*/
.alternar > input,
.alternar > input:checked + img,
.alternar > input + img + img {
  display: none;
}

/* Invertimos la lógica. Mostramos:
- La primera imagen cuando no esté marcada la casilla.
- La segunda imagen cuando lo esté.
*/
.alternar > input + img,
.alternar > input:checked + img + img {
  display: block;
}

.alternar > span {
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 24px;
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="alternar">
  <span>CLICK ME</span><input type="checkbox" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="Imagen 1" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/210/200" alt="Imagen 2" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

El error esta cuando se ejecuta mas de una ves el mismo evento, en este caso el input con su evento click y el del label, para solucionar el problema podrias usar `stopPropagation` para evitar que se propage el evento del input en todo el label.

Segun [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation):

> El método stopPropagation() de la interfaz Event evita la propagación adicional del evento actual en las fases de captura y bubbling.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#input');
let text = document.querySelector('.text');
let alternar = document.querySelector('.alternar');

input.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

alternar.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('purple');
});
```

```css
/* No mostramos:
- La casilla de verificación
- La primera imagen si está marcada la casilla.
- La segunda imagen si no lo está.
*/

.alternar>input,
.alternar>input:checked+img,
.alternar>input+img+img {
  display: none;
}


/* Invertimos la lógica. Mostramos:
- La primera imagen cuando no esté marcada la casilla.
- La segunda imagen cuando lo esté.
*/

.alternar>input+img,
.alternar>input:checked+img+img {
  display: block;
}

.alternar>span {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: red;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<label class="alternar">
<input type="checkbox" id="input" />
<span>CLICK ME</span>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="Imagen 1" />
<img src="https://picsum.photos/210/200" alt="Imagen 2" />
</label>
```